# portals contain many static pages, how can they generate these pages?

Tags: java, portal

I want to know what's the name of this kind of technology and if someone can give me references, will be appreciated.

Actually the website is developed with Java/C#, but not a really static website.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you mean, URLs look like static pages (http://something.com/path/resource.html), while actually they are generated by some server-side technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About "URLs which look like static pages":**

Many web development frameworks allow to configure [URL mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework#URL_mapping) - mechanism of mapping URL entered by user to specific dynamic script / function. AFAIK, for Java Spring and Stripes frameworks can do that.

Some web servers provide [Rewrite Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) functionality, which allows to do the same - call specific scripts on request to URL of some type.

**About performance:**

If you are anxious about performance, consider using some caching technology (for example, [memcached](http://www.memcached.org/), or even [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy)).

Comment: Is it possible to generate a static page when a new request comes, and then when next request comes, we just send it the saved static page ? will any framework do this ?

Comment: Of course, it is possible, but personally I never heard about such approach to web development. AFAIU, memory cache is much faster (since there's no disk read operations) and much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question.
If you're asking how they generate customized content that is sent to the browser as a static page, it's the classic way web servers work. They have an application that processes your request (which could be as simple as entering a search), create an html page containing the customized response and send it back. In the C# world this is usually done with ASP.NET.

Comment: if the server need to generate the page every requests, then the performance is really bad